# Automatically generate command to reproduce an object in the workspace

Tags: r

Suppose an object is already defined in the workspace:

```
a <- round( rnorm(10) )

[1]  0 -1 -1 -1 -1  0  2  1  1  1
```

How can I programatically generate a command which creates `a`?

For example, I would like to use the `a` in my workspace to generate the following string `codeToCreateA`:

```
codeToCreateA <- "a <- c( 0, -1, -1, -1, -1,  0,  2,  1,  1,  1)"
```

I'm interested in the general case, in which `a` could be any class of object, including a vector, list, or data frame.

Comment: You mean like `dput(a)`?  Not sure what you mean by "as a string"

Comment: @Bobby I don't understand your question. do you want to generate a `numeric` vector ?

Comment: Just updated the question slightly. I hope that helps. Yes, `dput(a)` works in this case. Thanks! I just tried it on a data frame and got this result `structure(list(A = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b"), B = 1:5), .Names = c("A", 
"B"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x22f5938>)`. How can I create the data frame again from this code?

Comment: @Bobby just assign the result of `dput(a)` to whatever variable name you want.

Comment: You can send it to file.  `dput(a, file="a.R")`, then use `dget()` to get it.  Something like `rm(a); assign("a", dget("a.R")); a` would do it.

Comment: Or just copy/paste. `a = structure(list(A = ....))` will create that data frame and assign it to the variable "a". The copy/pasteability is the [preferred method for sharing R objects on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/903061).

Comment: Yes, this was also part of my motivation for asking the question. `a <- structure(list(A = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b"), B = 1:5), .Names = c("A", "B"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame" ), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x22f5938>)` works if I remove the last argument. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`dput(A)` returns the structure of the object `A`. It can then be used to recreate `A` directly, or to share code for recreating a single object with others.

I've tested it on a vector, data frame, and list.

Here's an example for a data tablet (also of class data frame):

```
a <- structure(list(A = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b"), B = 1:5), 
.Names = c("A", "B"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), 
class = c("data.table", "data.frame" ), 
.internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x22f5938>)
```

Note that the last argument needs to be removed before executing this code. i.e.

```
b <- structure(list(A = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b"), B = 1:5), 
.Names = c("A", "B"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), 
class = c("data.table", "data.frame" ) )
```

The comments on the question above helped to prepare this answer.

Comment: This is a `data.table` not just a `data.frame`. Normal `data.frame` doesn't have `.internal.selfref ` argument

Comment: Thanks, I'll note that too. But was I right that it's necessary to remove that last argument?